# how to reuse the same table view in different views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ipad

In my app , i have UIScrollView in bottom of the page where it contains list of UIViews. i want display the same UITableView with same contents on all the views.  Can any one help me out of this?

Comment: do u want to show all the tables simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need in fact is the opposite : having one viewController managing your table AND a list of sub viewControllers managing your views. The the main controller load subView depending on the row selected (a bit like the tabviewcontroller does).