# Managing same CollectionView on different Views in ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, viewcontroller, reusability

I have a CollectionView on one of the screens. Selecting one of the cells transitions to another view. At this new view, at the bottom, I want to have the same collection to be presented.

So I have one ItemsCollectionController for the main screen - in ItemsCollectionController.m

And I have a WorkAreaController for the second screen. In the WorkArea.xib I added a CollectionView at the bottom of the screen. I would like to let the ItemsCollectionController to manage it.

Tried to manually instantiate the ItemsCollectionController with the WorkArea.xib when the WorkArea viewDidLoad - nothing.

Not only that I want the same class to handle both Collections. I would like even to have same instance of the ItemsCollectionController to do it. Can I just change the view outlet of the running instance ?

I saw this [seemingly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408701/how-to-reuse-the-same-table-view-in-different-views) but this is not what I want .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it.
Lets suppose I have a controller C1 managing a CollectionView.
Now I want to change to a different view, managed by controller C2 and on that view, I want still to show the contents of the CollectionView managed by C1.

The way I found to do it is :

1. Prior to switching to the C2.view :

   ```
    [C1.myCollectionView removeFromSuperView]
   ```

this will make sure the view can be reused.

2.Now lets switch to the new controller and its view

```
[UIView transitionFromView:C1.view
           toView:C2.view
            ....
             ...
```

1. And to add the C1.myCollectionView to the C2.view we need to modify the **viewDidLoad** of C2
   `[self.view addSubView:C1.collectionView]`
2. And now just make the collectionView to reload

`[C1.collectionView reloadData];`

Hope this helps to someone